# How to use the return value from React hook updater function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using the following code as an updater function for my state (inside hook).

While the console output works properly inside the callback, how can I access the value outside. I am returning `someStatus` and assign it to `x`. But `x` is printed as `undefined`.

Is there some issue with the code below?

```js
let x = setSomeStatus((someStatus) => {
    console.log("Some Status :::: :" + someStatus); // "XYZ"
    return someStatus;
});
console.log("x = " + x); // undefined
```

---

I tried below as suggested, but still do not get updated value outside the callback;

```
setSomeStatus((someStatus) => {
    console.log("File Status :::: :" + someStatus); // "XYZ"
    return someStatus;
});
console.log("someStatus = " + someStatus);
```

---

BELOW SEEMS TO BE WORKING (Please confirm if it looks good)

```
const onCellClicked = (e) => {
        if (e.data.status !== 'TO') {
            console.log(e);
            //let fileStatus;
            let fileType = (e.data.status === 'Y') ? 'O' : 'I';
            setCurrentFileStatus(e.data.status);
            setFileType(fileType);

            var tempObj = {};
            setCurrentFileStatus((fileStatus) => {
                setFileType((fileType) => {
                    tempObj.currentFileStatus = fileStatus;
                    tempObj.summaryDate = form.dateField;
                    tempObj.fileType = fileType;
                });             
            });
            setSharedData(tempObj);
            console.log("tempObj = " + tempObj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You transformed `x` into a function, but you are not calling it.

Comment: Is setSomeStatus a setState function? If so, why do you not not access the state directly but try to set `x` to it?

Comment: I get x is not a function if I try to invoke it

Comment: If you pass a callback to a setState function, the parameter it receives (in your case `someStatus`) is the previous value. You return that very same parameter without changing it, therefore the state is always set to the same `undefined` value. Read up on `Functional updates` in the link I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `setSomeStatus` is [a setState function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), the return statement of the callback you pass to setState will just return from the callback, and consequently set the state, but not actually return a value from the `setState` function.

As you anyways already have a state defined, you don't need to store it in a separate variable (`x` in your case), you can access it directly.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Type something to change the state</p>
      <input
        onInput={(e) =>
          setSomeState((prev) => {
            console.log("changing the state from", prev, "to", e.target.value);
            return e.target.value;
          })
        }
      />
      <h2>The state is {someState}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I still do not get the updated value (edited orig question with what I tried)

Comment: The state value (`someState` in my code snippet) always has the updated value. It can be accessed directly provided that it's properly defined with the `useState` hook

Comment: @copenndthagen that's because you return the old state value in your function so the new value is always the old one.

Comment: Ok..I made some changes and updated in my original question...I get the desired output with this...However could you please have a look and confirm if the updated code looks proper...

Comment: So basically I have a used callbacks for each of the 2 state variables